# Building PHP Download link

Tags: php

First I'm going to quote straight from the book

> basename() extracts the filename component of a path, so if
>   basename($_GET['file']) is different from $_GET['file'], you know there’s an attempt
>   to probe your server.

Let's say that I have this download link.

```
<a href="download.php?file=image.jpeg">Click here to download image</a>
```

and in download.php file, I have this line of code:

```
if (isset($_GET['file']) && basename($_GET['file']) == $_GET['file']) {
    // do something with the file
}
```

If I change the file query in the link (from the browser's address bar), say, I change it to:

```
download.php?file=passwords.txt
```

From what I can read from the condition line in download.php, it's not going to make a difference in the checking of the file query link, the condition could be read as:

```
isset($_GET['file']) // This evaluates to TRUE because now it contains passwords.txt
basename($_GET['file']) // This will contain passwords.txt
$_GET['file'] // This will contain passwords.txt
```

Does this mean that the attempt to prevent the user to inject malicious query from the browser using the condition in download.php is wrong? At least using the code from the book.

I can use an array to store the valid file that is safe for the user to download and check it using the `in_array()` function. Or is it that I read the code wrong?

Basically what I'm trying to say here is that if you change the file query in the link, the condition in download.php always evaluates to true. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct. See [`basename()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php).

Apparently it is not “the book” it is just “a book”  and I can't comment on that because I don't know the context. A simple implementation without changing a lot in your code is checking if there is a file with that path and having one database table with the files that you permit to be downloaded. There are many more ways that would require you to change a lot but they are better. E.g. never have your src or your repository in pubic_html and give authorization to downloads based on user privileges

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just want to know that I read the code right.